# Meaning of mean segment length

Tags: geometry

Inside the [“3, 4, 5 triangle”](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3,%204,%205%20triangle&lk=1&a=ClashPrefs_%2aMathWorld.345Triangle)  topic in Wolframalpha, one of the parameters is called mean segment length and it is given as:-

$$ \bar s = \frac{20460 + 9728\log2 + 5103\log3} {22500}$$

Help is needed for in explaining

(1) what does it mean?

(2) how does it formulated?

(3) Where does those values come from?

Comment: My guess is that it means the average length of a line segment with endpoints on the edge of the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the average length of a line segment determined by two points picked at random in the interior of an triangle. You can see more on it here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleLinePicking.html .

Comment: Would like to know more about "Just as a check, the article gives the exact same value for a 3,4,5 triangle as WolframAlpha." Like - What other values are being used for the checking to match that 'exact same value'? By 'exact same value', I presume you are talking about the value of the '(bar s)'.

Comment: @Mick I just wanted to say that the article gives the same value (of bar s) as  WolframAlpha for a 3,4,5 triangle, so that you did not have any confusion.